# Apps not showing in virtual device Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm currently learning android development but am running a small problem. The last two apps I've attempted to run (Following Bucky's android tutorials) have failed to appear in my virtual device.

**This is my build log:**

```
11:58:36 AM Gradle sync started
11:59:14 AM Gradle sync completed
11:59:16 AM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
11:59:30 AM Gradle build finished in 12s 258ms
12:19:21 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
12:19:24 PM Gradle build finished with 15 error(s) in 3s 20ms
12:19:33 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
12:19:56 PM Gradle build finished in 22s 797ms
12:32:59 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
12:33:01 PM Gradle build finished in 1s 608ms
```

**My build.gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'     
android { 
    compileSdkVersion 22 
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1" 
defaultConfig { 
    applicationId "com.example.alex.buckysgestures" 
    minSdkVersion 19 
    targetSdkVersion 22 
    versionCode 1 
    versionName "1.0" 
} 
buildTypes { 
    release { 
        minifyEnabled false 
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 
    } 
} 
} 
dependencies { 
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1' 
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Share your build.gradle (app) and your AVD Settings (The API level of you virtual device).

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Nexus one API 22,

Sorry dont know how to edit on overflow yet.

Comment: Well, I have edited you question. But you have shared the build.gradle of your project. You have to share build.gradle of your app module. There is 2 build.gradle in your project.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I findmy build.gradle for my app module. I'm alittle new to all this. Thanks.

Comment: It should be in your project's *app* folder.

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alex.buckysgestures"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}

Comment: I have edited the question again with your app build.gradle
Now its time to put an answer of your question

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. To improve future questions, can you explain how you have edited my posts to look like that?

Comment: click on edit button and check the source! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have successfully built your app, now you should install it on device. Be sure some device is connected (or virtual device), and run

```
 ./gradlew installDebug
```